# How can I turn off "mobile mode" for Stack Exchange chat?

Tags: support, chat, mobile-web

While having trouble getting Stack Exchange Chat to work on my travels in China, [somebody suggested I try the mobile version](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1538/140). (I'm using a netbook.)

That actually worked but now I'm in a different hotel in a different city and most of the sites I had trouble with previously now work.

But when I open SE chat in a new tab it automatically opens in mobile mode. It doesn't seem to have any button to switch to "non mobile mode".

It seems nobody has asked this before since my searches reveal nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both in the list of rooms and when inside a room, there is a "Full site" link available in the menu.

Either option will bring up the full site version of chat.

You can also just [visit chat via this link](https://chat.stackexchange.com?mobile=0). (i.e. append `?mobile=0` to the URL)

#### In room list:

> [image]

#### In room menu:

> [image]

Comment: Ah yes I looked in the menu and didn't spot the "full site" button but there it is! (-: